# SSRS - Group Consecutive Rows of Same Time Spans

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-grouping

Related to this [SQL question - Group consecutive rows of same value using time spans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244659/group-consecutive-rows-of-same-value-using-time-spans)

I want to convert this table:

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═════════╗
║ Classroom ║ CourseName ║  Lesson   ║ StartTime ║ EndTime ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═════════╣
║      1001 ║ Course 1   ║ Lesson 1  ║      0800 ║    0900 ║
║      1001 ║ Course 1   ║ Lesson 2  ║      0900 ║    1000 ║
║      1001 ║ Course 1   ║ Lesson 3  ║      1000 ║    1100 ║
║      1001 ║ Course 2   ║ Lesson 10 ║      1100 ║    1200 ║
║      1001 ║ Course 2   ║ Lesson 11 ║      1200 ║    1300 ║
║      1001 ║ Course 1   ║ Lesson 4  ║      1300 ║    1400 ║
║      1001 ║ Course 1   ║ Lesson 5  ║      1400 ║    1500 ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═════════╝
```

To this table:

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╦═══════════╦═════════╗
║ Classroom ║ CourseName ║ StartTime ║ EndTime ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╬═══════════╬═════════╣
║      1001 ║ Course 1   ║      0800 ║    1100 ║
║      1001 ║ Course 2   ║      1100 ║    1300 ║
║      1001 ║ Course 1   ║      1300 ║    1500 ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╩═══════════╩═════════╝
```

The SQL solution from the related question works but the query takes forever because I have a lot of data in my tables and the SQL Query is using 2 sub queries.
Actually the original table is a query with 3 joins in itself so the complexity is even bigger.

I am looking for an SSRS solution.
Is it possible using some "VB Magic" or other kind of magic in SSRS 2008 R2 to do this ?